# MySQL commands conversion to Yii create

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Firstly I'm not an expert in Yii, MySQL or PHP.

I'm designing my database tables with MySQL Workbench, I'm not able to avoid that the Workbench creating more than a primary index so CRUD doesn't work properly. Now I'm trying to convert the  MySQL code to create the tables in the create tool of Yii syntax. Are there any programs or extensions to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/database-command/

You can use that to create a dump of the database as a Yii migration (that's a bunch of PHP code with the MySQL commands to install your database). Migrations can then be imported using `yiic migrate`, assuming they're in the migrations folder, or by also providing a migration path (default location for dumps from that extension is the runtime folder).

Next you'll probably want to create a new migrations for all your database changes. See the [database migrations guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) for more info on how to do that.